# Need help in ASP.NET web application build and upload online

Tags: asp.net, build, upload, web

I have a web application in ASP.NET. Which has approx 200 ASPX pages with its CS files. 
everything i correct some issues or made changes on few .ASPX pages.
After these changes done, Do i need to build the whole application and upload online again ?
or the corrected files alone need to be upload online ?

kindly suggest

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer.  It depends.. Web Site vs Web Application.  .cs change vs .aspx change.

You will find this link a very good read.  [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)

I suggest reading the whole page but if you wanted a quick answer go down to the Deployment section.